Fill SQL junction table (sqlite)
Let's say I got

a studens table with student_id and student_name
a classes table with class_id and class_name
and a junction table with student_id and class_id

If a student with student_id=1 tells me all his classes names e.g. Math and English, how do I fill the junction table using only SQL

A more realistic scenario is the student telling you their name instead of their id.
CREATE TABLE students (student_id INT PRIMARY KEY, student_name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE classes (class_id INT PRIMARY KEY, class_name TEXT);
CREATE TABLE junction (student_id INT, class_id INT,
       FOREIGN KEY(student_id) REFERENCES students(student_id),
       FOREIGN KEY(class_id)   REFERENCES classes(class_id));

INSERT INTO students VALUES (1, 'John Doe');
INSERT INTO classes  VALUES (1, 'Math'), (2, 'English');

INSERT INTO junction
SELECT students.student_id, classes.class_id
FROM classes, students
WHERE class_name IN ('Math', 'English')
      AND student_name = 'John Doe';

SELECT * FROM junction;
/*
    1|1
    1|2
*/


Try this:
insert into junction_table(student_id, class_id)
select  1, cl.id
  from classes cl
 where cl.name in ('Math', 'English')
;

But, few input data. Where 1 is student_id = 1

That's it, Thank you very much! Didn't know you could place constant values in your select statement (select  1,...)
